# How to count and select points within a polygon ArcGIS?

Tags: c#, arcgis

I'm trying to create a button that counts and selects all points within a polygon.

```
protected override void OnClick()
    {   IActiveView activeView = ArcMap.Document.ActiveView;
        IEnumLayer featureClasses = activeView.FocusMap.Layers;

        if (featureClasses != null){
            ILayer layer ;
            while((layer = featureClasses.Next()) != null){

                if (layer as IFeatureLayer == null)
                    continue;
                if (layer.Name == "EX_BOUNDARY")//Name of polygon layer.{
                    var ftrLayer = layer as IFeatureLayer;
                    var ftrClass = ftrLayer.FeatureClass;

                    if (ftrClass == null)
                        continue;
                    GetSelectedPolygon(activeView, ftrClass, layer);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Method for getting the selected polygon, selecting and counting the points within it.

```
public void GetSelectedPolygon(IActiveView activeView, IFeatureClass featureClass, ILayer a)
    {

        //Check that the selected geometry is a polygon.
        IMap map = activeView.FocusMap;
        var selectedFeatures1 = (IEnumFeature)map.FeatureSelection;
        IFeature selectedFeature = selectedFeatures1.Next();
        IGeometry selectedGeometry = selectedFeature.ShapeCopy;


        if (selectedGeometry != null && selectedGeometry.GeometryType == esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolygon)
        {
            //execute query for all points inside polygon.
            ISpatialFilter spatialFilter = new SpatialFilterClass();
            spatialFilter.Geometry = selectedGeometry;
            spatialFilter.SpatialRel = esriSpatialRelEnum.esriSpatialRelIntersects;
            FeatureCursor featureCursor = null;
            var srchResult = featureClass.Search(spatialFilter, false);
            featureCursor = (FeatureCursor) featureClass.Search(spatialFilter, false);


            //select outcoming queries and their count.
            //map.FeatureSelection = srchResult as ISelection;
            IFeature singleSearchFeature = null;
            while ((singleSearchFeature = srchResult.NextFeature()) != null){
                //only looped once.
                map.SelectFeature(a,singleSearchFeature);
            }
            var count = srchResult.Fields.FieldCount;
            MessageBox.Show(count.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I'm very new to the whole GIS culture and I'm just starting my actual training. This is one of the main tasks I need to finish, I conceptually understand how things work, but it's all very new to me.

I'm suspecting that there is something wrong with the query I'm using for search, as what's happening is all my attempts of choosing a polygon then clicking my button end up with the messagebox saying 4 no matter how many points there are in the polygon, and it doesn't select any of them either.

Please help. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

"srchResult.Fields.FieldCount" is wrong. The FieldCount is the number of feature fields.

You can use this:

```
    protected override void OnClick()
    {
        try
        {
            IMxDocument document = (IMxDocument)ArcMap.Document;
            IMap map = document.FocusMap;
            IActiveView activeView = document.ActiveView;

            if (map.SelectionCount != 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Select one polygon.");
                return;
            }

            // Get the polygon for selecting features
            IEnumFeature features = (IEnumFeature)map.FeatureSelection;
            IFeature feature = features.Next();
            IGeometry geometry = feature.ShapeCopy;

            if (geometry.GeometryType != esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolygon)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Select one polygon.");
                return;
            }

            // Find layer to select features
            UID uid = new UIDClass() { Value = typeof(IFeatureLayer).GUID.ToString("B") };
            IEnumLayer layers = map.get_Layers(uid);

            string layerName = "Name of your points layer to select";

            ILayer layer = null;
            IFeatureLayer featureLayer = null;
            while ((layer = layers.Next()) != null)
            {
                if (layer.Name == layerName)
                {
                    featureLayer = (IFeatureLayer)layer;
                    break;
                }
            }

            map.ClearSelection();

            SelectByPolygon(featureLayer, geometry);

            activeView.PartialRefresh(esriViewDrawPhase.esriViewGeoSelection, null, activeView.Extent);
            ISelectionEvents selectionEvents = (ISelectionEvents)map;
            selectionEvents.SelectionChanged();

            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Number of selected features is {0}", map.SelectionCount));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Select features.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="featurelayer">Layers to select features.</param>
    /// <param name="polygon">Polygon geometry for select features.</param>
    public void SelectByPolygon(IFeatureLayer featurelayer, IGeometry polygon)
    {
        ISpatialFilter filter = new SpatialFilterClass();
        filter.Geometry = polygon;
        filter.SpatialRel = esriSpatialRelEnum.esriSpatialRelContains;

        var featureSelection = (IFeatureSelection)featurelayer;
        featureSelection.SelectFeatures(filter, esriSelectionResultEnum.esriSelectionResultNew, false);
        featureSelection.SelectionChanged();
    }
```

Comment: So I should just replace this with the method I had written GetSelectedPolygon, and simply call it in the onClick() event of the button ?

Comment: Yes, you can write this in the onClick event. You can check the GeometryType of parameter 'polygon' to esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolygon. If you don't understand something, you can ask, or see: [ArcObjects](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IFeatureSelection.htm)

Comment: I'll try it now, and what do I do if I want to exclude the points that exist or intersect with the polygon edges  ?

Comment: I tried your code and its not working, it keeps saying there are 2 points in whatever polygon I choose :/

Comment: Set variable 'layerName' to name of your points layer in the event OnClick.